# The parameter 'answerQuestion' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Function', but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz({
    @required this.answerQuestion,
    @required this.questions,
    @required this.questionIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['question'],
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
            .map((answer) =>
                Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']))
            .toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: showing this]

**the terminal shows this**

lib/quiz.dart:12:20: Error: The parameter 'answerQuestion' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Function', but the implicit
default value is 'null'.

- 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
  @required this.answerQuestion,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  lib/quiz.dart:13:20: Error: The parameter 'questions' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>', but the
  implicit default value is 'null'.
- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
  @required this.questions,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  lib/quiz.dart:14:20: Error: The parameter 'questionIndex' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'int', but the implicit default
  value is 'null'.
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
  @required this.questionIndex,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Try changing `@required` to `required`.

Answer (score 1):

The `@required` annotation is obsolete now, we have actual compiler support through the `required` keyword:

```
 Quiz({
    required this.answerQuestion,
    required this.questions,
    required this.questionIndex,
  });
```